# Difference in assignment of x=( $@ ) and x="$@"

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    snum=( $@ ) 
    echo $snum
fi
```

When I run the script like `./testscript.sh 1234 4568`
The output of echo command is only `1234`, so I guess I am not building an array of all positional arguments?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    snum="$@" 
    echo $snum
fi
```

and run `./testscript.sh 1234 4568`
The output is `1234 4568`

I am wondering why `snum=( $@ )` is only taking the first positional argument?

Comment: see also: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `"$@"` (incl. double quotes) in a list context to get **a list of** positional parameters, individually quoted.

Use `"$*"` (incl. double quotes) in a scalar context to get the positional parameters concatenated into **a single string** with the first character of `$IFS` (usually a space) as the delimiter.

Using `$@` unquoted (as in your first example) or using `"$@"` in a scalar context (as in your second example) rarely makes sense.  In the `bash` shell, using `"$@"` in a scalar context is the same as using `"$*"` with the first character of `$IFS` set to a space.

When using `snum=( "$@" )`, you create the array `snum`.  If you access the variable as `$snum`, you will get the first element of the array.  It is, in effect, the same as accessing `${snum[0]}`. Using `"${snum[@]}"` gives you a list of the individually quoted elements, in a similar manner as `"$@"` does.  Using `"${snum[*]}"` gives you the equivalent of `"$*"`, but for the array `snum`.

Assuming you want to create an array, `snum`, from the list of positional parameters and then print that array if it's not empty, you may use

```bash
#!/bin/bash

snum=( "$@" )

if [ "${#snum[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then
    printf '%s\n' "${snum[@]}"
fi
```

This prints the elements of `snum` on separate lines if the script was given arguments.

Example run:

```bash
bash-5.1$ ./script 1 2 3 "hello world" 4
1
2
3
hello world
4
```

Notice that the `hello world` argument is kept as a single argument, which would *not* be the case had you forgotten the quotes around `$@`.

To print the list of positional parameters at a single string, delimited by colons. The colons are inserted between the positional parameters by modifying the `$IFS` string.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

IFS=:
snum="$*"

if [ -n "$snum" ]; then
    printf '%s\n' "$snum"
fi
```

The difference here is that `snum` is now a single string, not an array of elements.  The script outputs the string if it is non-empty, i.e., if the script was given at least one non-empty argument.

Or, modifying our first example only slightly to keep using `snum` as an array,

```bash
#!/bin/bash

snum=( "$@" )

if [ "${#snum[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then
    IFS=:
    printf '%s\n' "${snum[*]}"
fi
```

Example run:

```bash
bash-5.1$ ./script 1 2 3 "hello world" 4
1:2:3:hello world:4
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var=( values )
```

Is an array variable assignment

```
var=value
```

is a scalar variable assignment (and with `var="$@"`, `var` is assigned the concatenation with space of the positional parameters as *one* string since its a scalar)

`$var` on an array expands to the element of index 0, same as `${var[0]}`, not all the elements of the array for which you need `${var[@]}`, a misdesign copied from the Korn shell.

Also note:

- leaving parameter expansions unquoted in list context is the split+glob operator, you almost never want to do that. Ironically, the only place you put quotes above is where they were not needed.
- `echo` can't be used to output arbitrary data in `bash`.

Here, you want:

```
#! /bin/bash -
print_space_separated() {
  local IFS=' '
  printf '%s\n' "$*"
}

if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
  snum=( "$@" )
  print_space_separated "${snum[@]}"
fi
```

In `zsh` whose array design is closer to that of `csh` than of `ksh`, you could have done:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
if (( $# > 0 )) {
  snum=( $argv )
  print -r -- $snum
}
```

(the `print -r` itself is from ksh)

But with the caveat that even though there's no split+glob upon parameter expansion in that shell, leaving array expansions unquoted like that still removes empty elements. To preserve them, you need the ksh syntax:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
if (( $# > 0 )) {
  snum=( "$@" )
  print -r -- "${snum[@]}"
}
```

(though the `"${snum[@]}"` can be shortened to `"$snum[@]"`).

Note that in `var="$@"` or `var="${array[@]}"`, `var` ends up containing a string made up of the positional parameters joined with the first character of `$IFS` in `zsh` and joined with spaces with `bash`. POSIX leaves the behaviour unspecified there, `$@` is only meant to be used quoted and in list contexts. To get the positional parameters joined with the first character of `$IFS` portably, use `"$*"` (in either list or non-list context).

To join elements of an array with arbitrary strings (as opposed to the first character of `$IFS`), use the `j` parameter expansion flag in `zsh`: `${(j[that-string])array}`. `bash` has no equivalent. `fish` has `string join -- that-string $array`.